# Debugging Angular production deployed application in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: javascript, angular, intellij-idea

I can debug Angular application in IntelliJ IDEA (JavaScript Debug) when I start app using `ng serve`.

But is there a way to attach IntelliJ JavaScript debugger to Angular application deployed on Weblogic server which is built with command `ng build --prod`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify URL of your application on WebLogic server as **URL:** in **JavaScript Debug** run configuration, (optionally) add remote URL mappings for the web server root (specify URL in the **Remote URL** field next to the corresponding folder) and hit **Debug**